# When did it become common knowledge that the Atlantis Expedition were from another galaxy?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

Obviously the Athosians find out pretty quick due to their situation of living with the Expedition at Atlantis. I can't really remember if they simply tell the Asurans who they are or if they find out from the hand-in-head thing. The Wraith... I'm not sure if they know straight from the beginning that Earth is in another galaxy or if they just know that it's somehow unknown to them and the rest of Pegasus. They certainly know at some point that it's not in Pegasus, even if they don't know it's in the Milky Way (otherwise the Superhive in the finale wouldn't have needed the signal from an alternate reality before heading there).

But what about everyone else in the galaxy? In 'Inquisition' - episode 5.13 - the Coalition folks seem to know. They say things like "since your arrival in this galaxy." I don't remember the Expedition exactly advertising that though. I think I can remember them being rather vague about stuff, saying that they "weren't from around here" or whatever. Now, I can certainly see how that information might leak out over time. An Athosian says something innocuous to a trader, Michael says stuff about it to his Hybrids, the Genii got some intel from when they took over Atlantis, things like that. But I certainly can't remember them telling someone outright and the other party acting suitably impressed; it is one thing to walk to different planets through a magic ring left by the Ancestors but it's quite another to be able to fly in spaceships from another galaxy.

I don't think it ever was made explicit, I just wondered if I missed something.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SFF.SE! Be sure to check out the [Help Centre](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help) for helpful hints for this site.

Comment: the wraith area able to read memories from people they are feeding on, i think a very early confrontation with the wraith leads to them finding out about who and where the sga team is from. i seem to remember something along these lines when the they wake up that wraith hive ship.

Comment: I do remember that first Queen getting all gooey at the thought of billions of humans on Earth and then wanting to know where it is. I just don't know if every Wraith knew that they were from another galaxy right from the start. In Allies they take two pieces of intel - how to better their hyperdrives and Earth's location. They obviously knew that they needed better engines to get there, but didn't know where they were going once they did. It may have just been the location of Earth IN the Milky Way though (they don't know that it doesn't matter if they get lost, there's planets everywhere).

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to the site:)

The Coalition folks had previous contact with the Genii. So it is probable the Genii could have informed the Coalition.

> from http://www.gateworld.net/atlantis/s5/transcripts/513.shtml
>
> SHEPPARD: What are you talkin' about?
>
> KELORE: The Genii had a plan to combat the Wraith, but they were thwarted when you betrayed them.
>
> SHEPPARD: Oh, is that what they told you, because that's not what I remember.

Comment: Since the Genii were backing the Coalition folks, yeah, they definitely had contact, but when did THEY find out? The last time we saw Ladon Radim is in 'The Return Part 1' when he makes an offer to Teyla and Ronon to join him in fighting the Wraith, as everyone has been kicked out by the Trians. He says simply that "[their] friends have all returned home." Not "they've gone back to their own galaxy" or something that would confirm it. It does seem to be common knowledge that they've "moved in" to Atlantis and are from somewhere else, but the Expedition were always coy about where that is.

Comment: Six weeks has passed after the departure of the Atlantis team. Enough time for the rumor that Sheppard and everyone else has left for good. Athosians will spread that rumor to their trading partners and the Genii are known to have spies all over the galaxy.